# Last-letter-first-letter sort

Tags: code-golf

Given a list/array of names(String) sort them such that each name is followed by a name which starts with the last character of the previous name.

## input

[
    Luis
    Hector
    Selena
    Emmanuel
    Amish
]

## output:

[
    Emmanuel
    Luis
    Selena
    Amish
    Hector
]

Comment: What do we output if it's not possible with the given list? What about if there is more than one possible solution?

Comment: Why is this Java-specific?

Comment: What's your objective winning criterion? Shortest code, most upvotes, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for tagging it as java problem. @Kendall Frey Objective is to get a solution, and may be optimize it further.

Comment: @Gareth A solution will always exist for the given input.